# Get array of chars from a base class property

Tags: c#, arrays, properties, calculator, base-class

I'm relatively new to programming, here is what I want to do:
I have a base class containing a property "Operator", its derivatives are classes for mathmatical operations, so the Operators are '-' '+' etc. Now I need to create an array of these Operators to use in my Calculator engine. I only have a list of the operation methods, how do I extract only the Operators and put them in an array? This is what I have already, but I'm asked to use the already existing Operators

```
char[] operatorArray = {'+', '-', '/', '*'};

            int indexOfLastOperatorBeforeSquare = leftOfSquare.LastIndexOfAny(operatorArray);
```

This is my base Class containing the Operator property:

```
public abstract class OperationBase
{
    public abstract string Operator { get; set; }
    public abstract string Execute(string leftOperator, string rightOperator);
}
```

and this is the constructor of the Addition Class as an example:

```
public Addition()
    {
        Operator = "+";
    }
```

Comment: You could use reflection to find all types derived from `OperationBase`, instantiate them and get the property value. (I would argue that `class Addition : OperatorBase` should have a const for its operator: it cannot change at runtime; this would save needing to instantiate it to get its operator.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you've derived  `OperationBase` in classes like `Addition`, `Substraction`, `Division`...

If you store these implementations in a `List<OperationBase>` (i.e. adding instances to the whole list: `list.Add(new Addition()); list.Add(new Subtraction());` and so on), you can extract the operators using LINQ:

```
List<OperationBase> operations = new List<OperationBase>();
operations.Add(new Addition());
operations.Add(new Division());
operations.Add(new Subtraction());

IEnumerable<char> operators = operations.Select(operation => operation.Operator[0]);
```

Now, the whole `operators` can be converted to array calling `operators.ToArray()`, which will contain the operators as characters:

```
char[] operatorChars = operators.ToArray();
```

Note that I had to obtain the operator character using `operation.Operator[0]`: your `OperationBase` defines that the operations provide their operator as `string` instead of `char`. If you want to avoid this, fix the whole property and turn it to `char` type, and the code will look as follows:

```
IEnumerable<char> operators = operations.Select(operation => operation.Operator);
```

Comment: I had already created that list because I needed it before, I just didn't know how to get the Operators out of there, and LINQ is something I haven't used before, I guess I'll have to get myself educated about that. Thank you very much, that works just fine!

Comment: @tweedledum11 this is another scenario: you want to get an operation by its type. `operations.OfType<Addition>().Single()`. It's just to open your curiosity ;)

Comment: I'm definitely curious, thanks for that, I actually tried .OfType<char> before to get the Operator out of the operations list, but that didn't work as I imagined :D. I'm reading up about IEnumerable now, I definitely need to understand your line of code there, don't want anything in my code that just magically works without me understanding why!